# Sonata media - No resizing

Tags: symfony, symfony-cmf, sonata-media-bundle

I would like to know if that's possible to get an image with {% path %} or {% media %} in a twig template from sonata, without crop/resize ? It seems that it's required to specify a format, but I would like to keep the original size in some case.

I have the idea to make a resizer that does nothing for this problem, but is it possible to specify a resizer by context and not a resizer for a provider in all contexts please ? Because I need to use a resizer in some case, but not in all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display your uploaded image without resize / crop in twig you can do :

```
{% media media, 'reference' %}
```

More details in the [documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/helpers.html#helpers) on how to use the twig helpers.

Comment: I'll try thank you, not really explicit in documentation... "Render the path to a sonata.media.provider.file context"